# Set the first element in list as last python

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I want to move the first item in python list

to go from this:

```
numbers = [3, 1, 2]
```

to this:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A dictionary has no order. Use `collections.OrderedDict` if you need that functionality.

Comment: There is no "first" or "last" element in a dictionary. The two dictionaries are equivalent.

Comment: use OrderedDict https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict although python3 dicts are ordered by insertsion, so you'd have to construct a new instance of the dict. But if you're relying on the runtime order you are not using dict as intended.

Comment: Since Python 3.7, dicts are ordered (they keep the insertion order), so this is possible by creating a new dict in the order you want. But maybe you're looking to implement a wrong solution to a different problem. What is your use case and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm dumb! I meant in a list, not a dict!!

Comment: Your example doesn't look like a list.

Comment: I know @KennyOstrom I have other values, not numbers, I just set them as numbers as example so it's easy to see what I mean!

Comment: You need to use pop() and insert(), to move them, or if you just want them sorted then use sort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new dictionary in the order you expect, they're insertion-ordered from Python 3.7!

However, do note that the order doesn't really matter as keys are retrieved from their hash!

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections like this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

numbers = {'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'one': 1}
dict_order = ['one', 'two', 'three']
ordered = OrderedDict((k, numbers[k]) for k in dict_order)
```

Comment: Since Python 3.7, you can do the same with a normal dict.

Comment: Yeah your right, I just thought I'd post it like this to be backwards compatible. It's also worth noting that dicts preserve insertion order as of 3.6

Comment: OrderedDict is still the way to go if you want *guaranteed* behaviour.

Comment: The behavior is guaranteed for 'normal' dicts since Python 3.7 (and was already implemented for CPython since 3.6) - From https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html : "the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec." Ordereddicts have a pair of additional methods though, and their comparison is order sensitive.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yeah I know, but OrderedDict is backwards compatible. Some embedded python isn't running 3.7. I still work with systems that use Python 2